# Partial TLS negotiation by some customer sites

Tags: ssl, smtp

We migrated an email-to-sms platform from a standard dedicated servers hosting centre into AWS recently and despite all our testing, a sub-set of our customers reported the service dead.

On checking, the affected custmers all use TLS. We can connect from our office via openssl to provide the TLS channel and perform SMTP commands as expected. However, the affected sites can connect fine but only receive the first part of the TLS certificate response. To be clear, the TLS certificate response when using openssl.exe is expected to be several console pages long but on the affected customer sites it seems truncated about a quarter of the of way down.

Can anyone offer a suggestion of what might be causing this? The customers claim no proxy or firewall interference.

Comment: Have you checked to see if Jumbo frames are present anythwere along the path with a ping test? https://blah.cloud/hardware/test-jumbo-frames-working/

Comment: @StefanLasiewski how would this affect an email. My understanding is that jumbo frames are an efficiency enhancement for high bandwidth applications like storage and stream. Our customers are known to have various network security layers so a ping test may not be feasible either, sadly.